# What is the white goo that comes out of bacon and how to prevent it?

Tags: meat, presentation

When frying bacon a white goo comes out of most of pre-packed bacon purchased from major supermarkets. Some say this is protein, some say it is nitrates leaching out. What exactly is it and how can I remove it before cooking as it ruins the presentation and congeals in the frying pan?

Comment: It might contain both proteins and nitrates.  And the only recommendation that I’ve seen for dealing with it is to parboil the bacon before finishing in a pan, but I’ve never actually tried it, so can’t confirm that it works)

Comment: @Joe you can effectively parboil *in* the pan by adding some water and cooking until it boils off, then finishing at a higher temp. I’ve done that once or twice and while it works well, I’ve no recollection on the effect of whether the residue mentioned in the question appears or not

Comment: @fyrepenguin : yes, but then you leave the stuff that’s released in the pan unless you skim the surface and such.  Big you retain more flavor rather than have it leach all into the water to be removed (or strained and saved to start some stock)